# Retrieving the last record in each group - MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, greatest-n-per-group, groupwise-maximum

There is a table `messages` that contains data as shown below:

```
Id   Name   Other_Columns
-------------------------
1    A       A_data_1
2    A       A_data_2
3    A       A_data_3
4    B       B_data_1
5    B       B_data_2
6    C       C_data_1
```

If I run a query `select * from messages group by name`, I will get the result as:

```
1    A       A_data_1
4    B       B_data_1
6    C       C_data_1
```

What query will return the following result?

```
3    A       A_data_3
5    B       B_data_2
6    C       C_data_1
```

That is, the last record in each group should be returned.

At present, this is the query that I use:

```
SELECT
  *
FROM (SELECT
  *
FROM messages
ORDER BY id DESC) AS x
GROUP BY name
```

But this looks highly inefficient. Any other ways to achieve the same result?

Comment: see accepted answer in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1379565/mysql-first-and-last-record-of-a-grouped-record-aggregate-functions for a more efficient solution

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/121387/684229

Comment: Why can't you just add DESC, i.e. select * from messages group by name DESC

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I SELECT rows with MAX(Column value), DISTINCT by another column in SQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/612231/how-can-i-select-rows-with-maxcolumn-value-distinct-by-another-column-in-sql)

Comment: @KimPrince It seems like the answer you are suggesting doesn't do what is expected! I just tried your method and it took FIRST row for each group and ordered DESC. It does NOT take the last row of each group

Comment: For more efficiency, see http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/groupwise_max

Comment: See This: https://paulund.co.uk/get-last-record-in-each-mysql-group

Comment: @DatsunBing your solution is the easiest and perfect one.

Comment: Came up with an interesting solution to this : https://stackoverflow.com/a/68894680/13457138

Comment: "last record" is not reliable if you do not specify an explicit `ORDER BY`.

Comment: @DatsunBing - The inner `ORDER BY` is ignored by the Optimizer.  The outer `GROUP BY` violates `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY`.

Comment: Can somebody please tell me why all databases don't use the only (in my opinion) sane result when using an aggregate function, which is to select the other fields *from the same row*?  To not do so not only doesn't make sense to me, be necessitates all these other methods which are *way more complicated*.

Comment: I was just looking for something different question and I found yours & I tried it in my way.. [answer](https://dbfiddle.uk/-L-bNsyq)

Answer (score 1403, accepted):

MySQL 8.0 now supports [windowing functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-functions.html), like almost all popular SQL implementations. With this standard syntax, we can write greatest-n-per-group queries:

```
WITH ranked_messages AS (
  SELECT m.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY name ORDER BY id DESC) AS rn
  FROM messages AS m
)
SELECT * FROM ranked_messages WHERE rn = 1;
```

This and other approaches to finding [groupwise maximal rows](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/example-maximum-column-group-row.html) are illustrated in the MySQL manual.

Below is the original answer I wrote for this question in 2009:

---

I write the solution this way:

```
SELECT m1.*
FROM messages m1 LEFT JOIN messages m2
 ON (m1.name = m2.name AND m1.id < m2.id)
WHERE m2.id IS NULL;
```

Regarding performance, one solution or the other can be better, depending on the nature of your data. So you should test both queries and use the one that is better at performance given your database.

For example, I have a copy of the [StackOverflow August data dump](https://archive.org/details/stackexchange).  I'll use that for benchmarking.  There are 1,114,357 rows in the `Posts` table.  This is running on [MySQL](https://www.mysql.com/) 5.0.75 on my Macbook Pro 2.40GHz.

I'll write a query to find the most recent post for a given user ID (mine).

**First using the technique [shown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1313120/sql-retrieving-the-last-record-in-each-group/1313140#1313140) by @Eric with the `GROUP BY` in a subquery:**

```
SELECT p1.postid
FROM Posts p1
INNER JOIN (SELECT pi.owneruserid, MAX(pi.postid) AS maxpostid
            FROM Posts pi GROUP BY pi.owneruserid) p2
  ON (p1.postid = p2.maxpostid)
WHERE p1.owneruserid = 20860;

1 row in set (1 min 17.89 sec)
```

Even the [`EXPLAIN` analysis](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/using-explain.html) takes over 16 seconds:

```
+----+-------------+------------+--------+----------------------------+-------------+---------+--------------+---------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table      | type   | possible_keys              | key         | key_len | ref          | rows    | Extra       |
+----+-------------+------------+--------+----------------------------+-------------+---------+--------------+---------+-------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY     | <derived2> | ALL    | NULL                       | NULL        | NULL    | NULL         |   76756 |             | 
|  1 | PRIMARY     | p1         | eq_ref | PRIMARY,PostId,OwnerUserId | PRIMARY     | 8       | p2.maxpostid |       1 | Using where | 
|  2 | DERIVED     | pi         | index  | NULL                       | OwnerUserId | 8       | NULL         | 1151268 | Using index | 
+----+-------------+------------+--------+----------------------------+-------------+---------+--------------+---------+-------------+
3 rows in set (16.09 sec)
```

**Now produce the same query result using [my technique](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/121387/fetch-the-row-which-has-the-max-value-for-a-column/123481#123481) with `LEFT JOIN`:**

```
SELECT p1.postid
FROM Posts p1 LEFT JOIN posts p2
  ON (p1.owneruserid = p2.owneruserid AND p1.postid < p2.postid)
WHERE p2.postid IS NULL AND p1.owneruserid = 20860;

1 row in set (0.28 sec)
```

The `EXPLAIN` analysis shows that both tables are able to use their indexes:

```
+----+-------------+-------+------+----------------------------+-------------+---------+-------+------+--------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table | type | possible_keys              | key         | key_len | ref   | rows | Extra                                |
+----+-------------+-------+------+----------------------------+-------------+---------+-------+------+--------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | p1    | ref  | OwnerUserId                | OwnerUserId | 8       | const | 1384 | Using index                          | 
|  1 | SIMPLE      | p2    | ref  | PRIMARY,PostId,OwnerUserId | OwnerUserId | 8       | const | 1384 | Using where; Using index; Not exists | 
+----+-------------+-------+------+----------------------------+-------------+---------+-------+------+--------------------------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

---

Here's the DDL for my `Posts` table:

```
CREATE TABLE `posts` (
  `PostId` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `PostTypeId` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `AcceptedAnswerId` bigint(20) unsigned default NULL,
  `ParentId` bigint(20) unsigned default NULL,
  `CreationDate` datetime NOT NULL,
  `Score` int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
  `ViewCount` int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
  `Body` text NOT NULL,
  `OwnerUserId` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `OwnerDisplayName` varchar(40) default NULL,
  `LastEditorUserId` bigint(20) unsigned default NULL,
  `LastEditDate` datetime default NULL,
  `LastActivityDate` datetime default NULL,
  `Title` varchar(250) NOT NULL default '',
  `Tags` varchar(150) NOT NULL default '',
  `AnswerCount` int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
  `CommentCount` int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
  `FavoriteCount` int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
  `ClosedDate` datetime default NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`PostId`),
  UNIQUE KEY `PostId` (`PostId`),
  KEY `PostTypeId` (`PostTypeId`),
  KEY `AcceptedAnswerId` (`AcceptedAnswerId`),
  KEY `OwnerUserId` (`OwnerUserId`),
  KEY `LastEditorUserId` (`LastEditorUserId`),
  KEY `ParentId` (`ParentId`),
  CONSTRAINT `posts_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`PostTypeId`) REFERENCES `posttypes` (`PostTypeId`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

---

**Note to commenters: If you want another benchmark with a different version of MySQL, a different dataset, or different table design, feel free to do it yourself. I have shown the technique above. Stack Overflow is here to show you how to do software development work, not to do all the work for you.**

Comment: Really? What happens if you have a ton of entries? For example, if you're working w/ an in-house version control, say, and you have a ton of versions per file, that join result would be massive. Have you ever benchmarked the subquery method with this one? I'm pretty curious to know which would win, but not curious enough to not ask you first.

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit the purpose of the condition "WHERE p2.postid IS NULL"? Wouldn't it contradict with the other condition "p1.postid < p2.postid"?

Comment: @KatherineChen, it has to do with the way `LEFT [OUTER] JOIN` works. If that join finds no matches for a given row in `m1`, then it will still return that row `m1`, but all the columns of `m2` will be NULL.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation! So this would lead it to match either the standalone record (m1.name = m2.name and no other ids associated with the same name) or the largest id given the same name (m1.name = m2.name and m1.id > m2.id).

Comment: @KatherineChen, I would describe it as: no other row is found with the same `name` and a greater `id`, therefore `m1` must be the row with the greatest `id` for that given value of `name`.

Comment: it would be nice if you benchmarked the windows function version too

Comment: @ysth I would hope that the point of Stack Overflow is to demonstrate techniques for readers, so they can be empowered to do more work themselves. The goal is not to do _all_ the work for them.

Comment: there is an edge case where the filter criteria for two+ records is exactly the same, then it will return multiple records. e.g. if your data looks like `m1.name = m2.name AND m1.id = m2.id`

Comment: @WiR3D, We assume that `id` is a unique key. If it is not, then you're right, you need to use some other column that can differentiate rows with the same `name`. This is why the ROW_NUMBER() window function is so useful, because you might not have such a column.

Comment: 2 cents here, but this was significantly faster than the `max` solution.

Comment: I realize that this post is rather old, but I happened to look at it today.  And I don't think that the "Eric" query is optimized properly.  The condition should be (IMO) `ON (p1.owneruserid = p2.owneruserid AND p1.postid = p2.maxpostid`.  As it is, I think that it has to generate a maximum `postid` for every user.  But you only need it for 20860.  You're a prolific poster, but I don't believe that you had a million posts in a single month.  The 1384 that you did have should be tractable, as it was in your LEFT JOIN.  Your version of "Eric" only works at all because one user per post.

Comment: @mdfst13 - yes, one could put the same WHERE clause into the subquery. Good point. Anyway, I got used to my LEFT JOIN solution many years ago, because it was so long ago, MySQL didn't even support subqueries.

Answer (score 182):

*UPD: 2017-03-31, the version [5.7.5](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/mysql/5.7/en/news-5-7-5.html#mysqld-5-7-5-sql-mode) of MySQL made the ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY switch enabled by default (hence, non-deterministic GROUP BY queries became disabled). Moreover, they updated the GROUP BY implementation and the solution might not work as expected anymore even with the disabled switch. One needs to check.*

Bill Karwin's solution above works fine when item count within groups is rather small, but the performance of the query becomes bad when the groups are rather large, since the solution requires about `n*n/2 + n/2` of only `IS NULL` comparisons.

I made my tests on a InnoDB table of `18684446` rows with `1182` groups. The table contains testresults for functional tests and has the `(test_id, request_id)` as the primary key. Thus, `test_id` is a group and I was searching for the last `request_id` for each `test_id`.

Bill's solution has already been running for several hours on my dell e4310 and I do not know when it is going to finish even though it operates on a coverage index (hence `using index` in EXPLAIN).

I have a couple of other solutions that are based on the same ideas:

- if the underlying index is BTREE index (which is usually the case), the largest `(group_id, item_value)` pair is the last value within each `group_id`, that is the first for each `group_id` if we walk through the index in descending order;
- if we read the values which are covered by an index, the values are read in the order of the index;
- each index implicitly contains primary key columns appended to that (that is the primary key is in the coverage index). In solutions below I operate directly on the primary key, in you case, you will just need to add primary key columns in the result.
- in many cases it is much cheaper to collect the required row ids in the required order in a subquery and join the result of the subquery on the id. Since for each row in the subquery result MySQL will need a single fetch based on primary key, the subquery will be put first in the join and the rows will be output in the order of the ids in the subquery (if we omit explicit ORDER BY for the join)

[3 ways MySQL uses indexes](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2009/09/12/3-ways-mysql-uses-indexes) is a great article to understand some details.

**Solution 1**

This one is incredibly fast, it takes about 0,8 secs on my 18M+ rows:

```
SELECT test_id, MAX(request_id) AS request_id
FROM testresults
GROUP BY test_id DESC;
```

If you want to change the order to ASC, put it in a subquery, return the ids only and use that as the subquery to join to the rest of the columns:

```
SELECT test_id, request_id
FROM (
    SELECT test_id, MAX(request_id) AS request_id
    FROM testresults
    GROUP BY test_id DESC) as ids
ORDER BY test_id;
```

This one takes about 1,2 secs on my data.

**Solution 2**

Here is another solution that takes about 19 seconds for my table:

```
SELECT test_id, request_id
FROM testresults, (SELECT @group:=NULL) as init
WHERE IF(IFNULL(@group, -1)=@group:=test_id, 0, 1)
ORDER BY test_id DESC, request_id DESC
```

It returns tests in descending order as well. It is much slower since it does a full index scan but it is here to give you an idea how to output N max rows for each group.

The disadvantage of the query is that its result cannot be cached by the query cache.

Answer (score 136):

Use your [subquery](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/subqueries.html) to return the correct grouping, because you're halfway there.

Try this:

```
select
    a.*
from
    messages a
    inner join 
        (select name, max(id) as maxid from messages group by name) as b on
        a.id = b.maxid
```

If it's not `id` you want the max of:

```
select
    a.*
from
    messages a
    inner join 
        (select name, max(other_col) as other_col 
         from messages group by name) as b on
        a.name = b.name
        and a.other_col = b.other_col
```

This way, you avoid correlated subqueries and/or ordering in your subqueries, which tend to be very slow/inefficient.

Comment: This works as long as max(id) is unique between groups. Otherwise you can add additional join condition by group identifier as seen here https://stackoverflow.com/a/7745635/3163618 tests http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f13270/2/0

Answer (score 111):

I arrived at a different solution, which is to get the IDs for the last post within each group, then select from the messages table using the result from the first query as the argument for a `WHERE x IN` construct:

```
SELECT id, name, other_columns
FROM messages
WHERE id IN (
    SELECT MAX(id)
    FROM messages
    GROUP BY name
);
```

I don't know how this performs compared to some of the other solutions, but it worked spectacularly for my table with 3+ million rows. (4 second execution with 1200+ results)

*This should work both on MySQL and SQL Server.*

Comment: This solution is crashing mysql server / service. I have checked it with 10 million records, not recommend this solution. Using IN in this case is very worst.

Comment: @Kamlesh Perhaps you are missing some indexes? Also this solution is nearly 10 years old, maybe some update has changed behavior or performance with this query.

Comment: Nice and elegant solution. Just a little improvement to make it work even with not univoque sorting attributes.
SELECT not_univoque_id, name, other_columns
FROM messages
WHERE (name, not_univoque_id) IN (
    SELECT name, MAX(not_univoque_id)
    FROM messages
    GROUP BY name
);

Comment: This even works with Firebird 1.0.3!

Comment: Good answer, This link is like your answer https://thispointer.com/retrieving-the-last-record-in-each-group-mysql/

Comment: This works as long as MAX(id) is unique among groups. Otherwise you can also match on the pair (MAX(id), Name) if supported by your engine. https://stackoverflow.com/a/7745679/3163618

Comment: Be sure to have `INDEX(name)`

Answer (score 55):

Solution by sub query [fiddle Link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a2bdc/1)

```
select * from messages where id in
(select max(id) from messages group by Name)
```

Solution By join condition [fiddle link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a2bdc/3)

```
select m1.* from messages m1 
left outer join messages m2 
on ( m1.id<m2.id and m1.name=m2.name )
where m2.id is null
```

Reason for this post is to give fiddle link only.
Same SQL is already provided in other answers.

Answer (score 23):

We will look at how you can use MySQL at getting the last record in a Group By of records. For example if you have this result set of posts.

| id | category_id | post_title |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | Title 1 |
| 2 | 1 | Title 2 |
| 3 | 1 | Title 3 |
| 4 | 2 | Title 4 |
| 5 | 2 | Title 5 |
| 6 | 3 | Title 6 |

I want to be able to get the last post in each category which are Title 3, Title 5 and Title 6. To get the posts by the category you will use the MySQL Group By keyboard.

```
select * from posts group by category_id
```

But the results we get back from this query is.

| id | category_id | post_title |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | Title 1 |
| 4 | 2 | Title 4 |
| 6 | 3 | Title 6 |

The group by will always return the first record in the group on the result set.

```
SELECT id, category_id, post_title
FROM posts
WHERE id IN (
    SELECT MAX(id)
    FROM posts
    GROUP BY category_id );
```

This will return the posts with the highest IDs in each group.

| id | category_id | post_title |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 1 | Title 3 |
| 5 | 2 | Title 5 |
| 6 | 3 | Title 6 |

[Reference Click Here](https://paulund.co.uk/get-last-record-in-each-mysql-group)

Answer (score 17):

An approach with considerable speed is as follows.

```
SELECT * 
FROM messages a
WHERE Id = (SELECT MAX(Id) FROM messages WHERE a.Name = Name)
```

**Result**

```
Id  Name    Other_Columns
3   A   A_data_3
5   B   B_data_2
6   C   C_data_1
```

Comment: This even works with Firebird 1.0.3! ... and seems to be "faster" than https://stackoverflow.com/a/9368897/2932052

Comment: This is really slow on a large dataset.

Answer (score 13):

Here are two suggestions.  First, if mysql supports ROW_NUMBER(), it's very simple:

```
WITH Ranked AS (
  SELECT Id, Name, OtherColumns,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
      PARTITION BY Name
      ORDER BY Id DESC
    ) AS rk
  FROM messages
)
  SELECT Id, Name, OtherColumns
  FROM messages
  WHERE rk = 1;
```

I'm assuming by "last" you mean last in Id order. If not, change the ORDER BY clause of the ROW_NUMBER() window accordingly. If ROW_NUMBER() isn't available, this is another solution:

Second, if it doesn't, this is often a good way to proceed:

```
SELECT
  Id, Name, OtherColumns
FROM messages
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT * FROM messages as M2
  WHERE M2.Name = messages.Name
  AND M2.Id > messages.Id
)
```

In other words, select messages where there is no later-Id message with the same Name.

Comment: MySQL doesn't support ROW_NUMBER() or CTE's.

Comment: MySQL 8.0 (and MariaDB 10.2) now support `ROW_NUMBER()` and CTEs.

Comment: Maybe readability improves by using two aliases (`a` and `b`), like so `SELECT * FROM messages a WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM messages as b WHERE a.Name = b.Name AND a.Id > b.Id)`

Comment: How is first version better? Second one is very clear and fast.

Answer (score 9):

Clearly there are lots of different ways of getting the same results, your question seems to be what is an efficient way of getting the last results in each group in MySQL. If you are working with huge amounts of data and assuming you are using InnoDB with even the latest versions of MySQL (such as 5.7.21 and 8.0.4-rc) then there might not be an efficient way of doing this.

We sometimes need to do this with tables with even more than 60 million rows.

For these examples I will use data with only about 1.5 million rows where the queries would need to find results for all groups in the data. In our actual cases we would often need to return back data from about 2,000 groups (which hypothetically would not require examining very much of the data).

I will use the following tables:

```
CREATE TABLE temperature(
  id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
  groupID INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL, 
  recordedTimestamp TIMESTAMP NOT NULL, 
  recordedValue INT NOT NULL,
  INDEX groupIndex(groupID, recordedTimestamp), 
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE selected_group(id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY(id));
```

The temperature table is populated with about 1.5 million random records, and with 100 different groups.
The selected_group is populated with those 100 groups (in our cases this would normally be less than 20% for all of the groups).

As this data is random it means that multiple rows can have the same recordedTimestamps. What we want is to get a list of all of the selected groups in order of groupID with the last recordedTimestamp for each group, and if the same group has more than one matching row like that then the last matching id of those rows.

If hypothetically MySQL had a last() function which returned values from the last row in a special ORDER BY clause then we could simply do:

```
SELECT 
  last(t1.id) AS id, 
  t1.groupID, 
  last(t1.recordedTimestamp) AS recordedTimestamp, 
  last(t1.recordedValue) AS recordedValue
FROM selected_group g
INNER JOIN temperature t1 ON t1.groupID = g.id
ORDER BY t1.recordedTimestamp, t1.id
GROUP BY t1.groupID;
```

which would only need to examine a few 100 rows in this case as it doesn't use any of the normal GROUP BY functions. This would execute in 0 seconds and hence be highly efficient.
Note that normally in MySQL we would see an ORDER BY clause following the GROUP BY clause however this ORDER BY clause is used to determine the ORDER for the last() function, if it was after the GROUP BY then it would be ordering the GROUPS. If no GROUP BY clause is present then the last values will be the same in all of the returned rows.

However MySQL does not have this so let's look at different ideas of what it does have and prove that none of these are efficient.

**Example 1**

```
SELECT t1.id, t1.groupID, t1.recordedTimestamp, t1.recordedValue
FROM selected_group g
INNER JOIN temperature t1 ON t1.id = (
  SELECT t2.id
  FROM temperature t2 
  WHERE t2.groupID = g.id
  ORDER BY t2.recordedTimestamp DESC, t2.id DESC
  LIMIT 1
);
```

This examined 3,009,254 rows and took ~0.859 seconds on 5.7.21 and slightly longer on 8.0.4-rc

**Example 2**

```
SELECT t1.id, t1.groupID, t1.recordedTimestamp, t1.recordedValue 
FROM temperature t1
INNER JOIN ( 
  SELECT max(t2.id) AS id   
  FROM temperature t2
  INNER JOIN (
    SELECT t3.groupID, max(t3.recordedTimestamp) AS recordedTimestamp
    FROM selected_group g
    INNER JOIN temperature t3 ON t3.groupID = g.id
    GROUP BY t3.groupID
  ) t4 ON t4.groupID = t2.groupID AND t4.recordedTimestamp = t2.recordedTimestamp
  GROUP BY t2.groupID
) t5 ON t5.id = t1.id;
```

This examined 1,505,331 rows and took ~1.25 seconds on 5.7.21 and slightly longer on 8.0.4-rc

**Example 3**

```
SELECT t1.id, t1.groupID, t1.recordedTimestamp, t1.recordedValue 
FROM temperature t1
WHERE t1.id IN ( 
  SELECT max(t2.id) AS id   
  FROM temperature t2
  INNER JOIN (
    SELECT t3.groupID, max(t3.recordedTimestamp) AS recordedTimestamp
    FROM selected_group g
    INNER JOIN temperature t3 ON t3.groupID = g.id
    GROUP BY t3.groupID
  ) t4 ON t4.groupID = t2.groupID AND t4.recordedTimestamp = t2.recordedTimestamp
  GROUP BY t2.groupID
)
ORDER BY t1.groupID;
```

This examined 3,009,685 rows and took ~1.95 seconds on 5.7.21 and slightly longer on 8.0.4-rc

**Example 4**

```
SELECT t1.id, t1.groupID, t1.recordedTimestamp, t1.recordedValue
FROM selected_group g
INNER JOIN temperature t1 ON t1.id = (
  SELECT max(t2.id)
  FROM temperature t2 
  WHERE t2.groupID = g.id AND t2.recordedTimestamp = (
      SELECT max(t3.recordedTimestamp)
      FROM temperature t3 
      WHERE t3.groupID = g.id
    )
);
```

This examined 6,137,810 rows and took ~2.2 seconds on 5.7.21 and slightly longer on 8.0.4-rc

**Example 5**

```
SELECT t1.id, t1.groupID, t1.recordedTimestamp, t1.recordedValue
FROM (
  SELECT 
    t2.id, 
    t2.groupID, 
    t2.recordedTimestamp, 
    t2.recordedValue, 
    row_number() OVER (
      PARTITION BY t2.groupID ORDER BY t2.recordedTimestamp DESC, t2.id DESC
    ) AS rowNumber
  FROM selected_group g 
  INNER JOIN temperature t2 ON t2.groupID = g.id
) t1 WHERE t1.rowNumber = 1;
```

This examined 6,017,808 rows and took ~4.2 seconds on 8.0.4-rc

**Example 6**

```
SELECT t1.id, t1.groupID, t1.recordedTimestamp, t1.recordedValue 
FROM (
  SELECT 
    last_value(t2.id) OVER w AS id, 
    t2.groupID, 
    last_value(t2.recordedTimestamp) OVER w AS recordedTimestamp, 
    last_value(t2.recordedValue) OVER w AS recordedValue
  FROM selected_group g
  INNER JOIN temperature t2 ON t2.groupID = g.id
  WINDOW w AS (
    PARTITION BY t2.groupID 
    ORDER BY t2.recordedTimestamp, t2.id 
    RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING
  )
) t1
GROUP BY t1.groupID;
```

This examined 6,017,908 rows and took ~17.5 seconds on 8.0.4-rc

**Example 7**

```
SELECT t1.id, t1.groupID, t1.recordedTimestamp, t1.recordedValue 
FROM selected_group g
INNER JOIN temperature t1 ON t1.groupID = g.id
LEFT JOIN temperature t2 
  ON t2.groupID = g.id 
  AND (
    t2.recordedTimestamp > t1.recordedTimestamp 
    OR (t2.recordedTimestamp = t1.recordedTimestamp AND t2.id > t1.id)
  )
WHERE t2.id IS NULL
ORDER BY t1.groupID;
```

This one was taking forever so I had to kill it.

Comment: This is a different problem. And the solution is a huge UNION ALL query.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel I guess you are joking about the huge UNION ALL. Besides the fact that one would need to know all of the selected groups in advance, and that with 2,000 selected groups that would be an incredibly huge query, it would perform even worse than the fastest example above, so no, that would not be a solution.

Comment: I'm absolutely serious. I've tested that in the past with a couple of hundred groups. When you need to handle ties in big groups, UNION ALL is the only way in MySQL to force an optimal execution plan. `SELECT DISTINCT(groupID)` is fast and will give you all data that you need to construct such a query. You should be fine with the query size as long as it doesn't exceed `max_allowed_packet`, which defaults to 4MB in MySQL 5.7.

Answer (score 7):

Here is another way to get the last related record using `GROUP_CONCAT` with order by and `SUBSTRING_INDEX` to pick one of the record from the list

```
SELECT 
  `Id`,
  `Name`,
  SUBSTRING_INDEX(
    GROUP_CONCAT(
      `Other_Columns` 
      ORDER BY `Id` DESC 
      SEPARATOR '||'
    ),
    '||',
    1
  ) Other_Columns 
FROM
  messages 
GROUP BY `Name`
```

Above query will group the all the `Other_Columns` that are in same `Name` group  and using `ORDER BY id DESC` will join all the `Other_Columns` in a specific group in descending order  with the provided separator in my case i have used `||` ,using `SUBSTRING_INDEX` over this list will pick the first one

### [Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/843079/4)

Comment: Be aware that `group_concat_max_len` limits how many rows you can handle.

Answer (score 7):

Hi @Vijay Dev if your table **messages** contains **Id** which is auto increment primary key then to fetch the latest record basis on the primary key your query should read as below:

```
SELECT m1.* FROM messages m1 INNER JOIN (SELECT max(Id) as lastmsgId FROM messages GROUP BY Name) m2 ON m1.Id=m2.lastmsgId
```

Comment: This one the fastest i found

Comment: This is one is also nice b/c limit and offset can be used in the subquery (or whatever it is called when a query is used in a join). MySQL does not allow limit/offset in typical subqueries, but they are allowed for joins like this.

Answer (score 7):

If you need the most recent or oldest record of a text column in a grouped query, and you would rather not use a subquery, you can do this...

Ex. You have a list of movies and need to get the count in the series and the latest movie

| id | series | name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Star Wars | A New hope |
| 2 | Star Wars | The Empire Strikes Back |
| 3 | Star Wars | Return of The Jedi |

```
SELECT COUNT(id), series, SUBSTRING(MAX(CONCAT(id, name)), LENGTH(id) + 1), 
FROM Movies
GROUP BY series
```

This returns...

| id | series | name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | Star Wars | Return of The Jedi |

MAX will return the row with the highest value, so by concatenating the id to the name, you now will get the newest record, then just strip off the id for your final result.

More efficient than using a subquery.

So for the given example:

```
SELECT MAX(Id), Name, SUBSTRING(MAX(CONCAT(Id, Other_Columns)), LENGTH(Id) + 1), 
FROM messages
GROUP BY Name
```

Happy coding, and "May The Force Be With You" :)

Comment: This may not work, Let's suppose in your example
The id of "A New hope" was 9 and the id of "Return of The Jedi" was 10.
This is because the MAX function for the Concatenation of the id and name would be doing it on a string. Thus "9A New hope" would be having higher order than "10Return of The Jedi"

Answer (score 6):

```
SELECT 
  column1,
  column2 
FROM
  table_name 
WHERE id IN 
  (SELECT 
    MAX(id) 
  FROM
    table_name 
  GROUP BY column1) 
ORDER BY column1 ;
```

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit on your answer? Why is your query preferrable to Vijays original query?

Answer (score 6):

You can take view from here as well.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ef42b/9

**FIRST SOLUTION**

```
SELECT d1.ID,Name,City FROM Demo_User d1
INNER JOIN
(SELECT MAX(ID) AS ID FROM Demo_User GROUP By NAME) AS P ON (d1.ID=P.ID);
```

**SECOND SOLUTION**

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM Demo_User ORDER BY ID DESC) AS T GROUP BY NAME ;
```

Answer (score 5):

**

***Hi, this query might help :***

**

```
SELECT 
  *
FROM 
  message 

WHERE 
  `Id` IN (
    SELECT 
      MAX(`Id`) 
    FROM 
      message 
    GROUP BY 
      `Name`
  ) 
ORDER BY 
   `Id` DESC
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
SELECT jos_categories.title AS name,
       joined .catid,
       joined .title,
       joined .introtext
FROM   jos_categories
       INNER JOIN (SELECT *
                   FROM   (SELECT `title`,
                                  catid,
                                  `created`,
                                  introtext
                           FROM   `jos_content`
                           WHERE  `sectionid` = 6
                           ORDER  BY `id` DESC) AS yes
                   GROUP  BY `yes`.`catid` DESC
                   ORDER  BY `yes`.`created` DESC) AS joined
         ON( joined.catid = jos_categories.id )
```

Answer (score 4):

I've not yet tested with large DB but I think this could be faster than joining tables:

```
SELECT *, Max(Id) FROM messages GROUP BY Name
```

Comment: This returns arbitrary data. In other words there returned columns might not be from the record with MAX(Id).

Comment: Useful to select the max Id from a set of record with WHERE condition : "SELECT Max(Id) FROM Prod WHERE Pn='" + Pn + "'" It returns the max Id from a set of records with same Pn.In c# use reader.GetString(0) to get the result

Comment: Why did this post get positive votes in the first place? In my opinion, it totally misses the point.

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE primary_key IN (SELECT MAX(primary_key) FROM table_name GROUP BY column_name )
```

Answer (score 4):

i find best solution in https://dzone.com/articles/get-last-record-in-each-mysql-group

```
select * from `data` where `id` in (select max(`id`) from `data` group by `name_id`)
```

Comment: Didn't you see this query in the answers that are already posted?

Answer (score 3):

The below query will work fine as per your question.

```
SELECT M1.* 
FROM MESSAGES M1,
(
 SELECT SUBSTR(Others_data,1,2),MAX(Others_data) AS Max_Others_data
 FROM MESSAGES
 GROUP BY 1
) M2
WHERE M1.Others_data = M2.Max_Others_data
ORDER BY Others_data;
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want the last row for each `Name`, then you can give a row number to each row group by the `Name` and order by `Id` in descending order.

**QUERY**

```
SELECT t1.Id, 
       t1.Name, 
       t1.Other_Columns
FROM 
(
     SELECT Id, 
            Name, 
            Other_Columns,
    (
        CASE Name WHEN @curA 
        THEN @curRow := @curRow + 1 
        ELSE @curRow := 1 AND @curA := Name END 
    ) + 1 AS rn 
    FROM messages t, 
    (SELECT @curRow := 0, @curA := '') r 
    ORDER BY Name,Id DESC 
)t1
WHERE t1.rn = 1
ORDER BY t1.Id;
```

## [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7c6d90/3)

Answer (score 3):

Here is my solution:

```
SELECT 
  DISTINCT NAME,
  MAX(MESSAGES) OVER(PARTITION BY NAME) MESSAGES 
FROM MESSAGE;
```

Comment: This doesn't return the latest message per name. And it's just an overcomplicated version of `SELECT NAME, MAX(MESSAGES) MESSAGES FROM MESSAGE GROUP BY NAME`.

Comment: Furthermore, this formulation is grossly inefficient.

Answer (score 3):

If performance is really your concern you can introduce a new column on the table called `IsLastInGroup` of type BIT.

Set it to true on the columns which are last and maintain it with every row insert/update/delete. Writes will be slower, but you'll benefit on reads. It depends on your use case and I recommend it only if you're read-focused.

So your query will look like:

```
SELECT * FROM Messages WHERE IsLastInGroup = 1
```

Comment: Some tables in Moodle has a flag column like this.

Answer (score 3):

MariaDB 10.3 and newer using [GROUP_CONCAT](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/group_concat/).

The idea is to use `ORDER BY` + `LIMIT`:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(id ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1) AS id,
       name,
       GROUP_CONCAT(Other_columns ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1) AS Other_columns
FROM t
GROUP BY name;
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=85d1fe8efc39f44a6723303522e0e23b)**

Answer (score 3):

In my **quest for a universal groupwise-max**, I've seen many answers and blog posts on the subject. Even [my favorite](https://explainextended.com/2009/11/24/mysql-selecting-records-holding-group-wise-maximum-on-a-unique-column/) (actually part of a fantastic series on the subject) failed to identify a portable solution, instead diving deep into specifics per RDMBS.

Luckily, **a portable solution does exist**!

The secondary index you need for this is `name`. (`name, id` would be identical, as the primary key is always included implicitly.)

Create groups of the `message`s, and use a dependent subquery to get the latest row for each group.

```sql
SELECT m.*

-- Step 1: Start by obtaining the groupwise maximums
FROM
(
    SELECT (
        -- Step 1b: Find the ID of the group maximum by seeking in the index
        SELECT id
        FROM messages m
        WHERE m.name = groups.name
        ORDER BY m.name DESC, m.id DESC -- Match the index EXACTLY, and indicate direction
        LIMIT 1
    ) AS id

    -- Step 1a: Find the groups by seeking through the index
    FROM messages AS groups
    GROUP BY groups.name
) AS maxes

-- Step 2: For each group, join the max row by ID
-- This neatly separates any potential followup SQL from the groupwise-max tactics
INNER JOIN messages m ON m.id = maxes.id
;
```

This is portable because it requires only the following combination of building blocks:

- Indexed `GROUP BY`.
- Indexed `SELECT` with `ORDER BY [ASC/DESC]` and `LIMIT/TOP`.
- Dependent subqueries.

Just be sure to have the correct index: `GroupKeyColumn(s), GroupWinnerColumn(s), PrimaryKeyColumn(s)`.

In OP's case, the group key is `name`, the group's winner is determined by `id`, and the primary key is already covered by that, so: `name, id`.

Many have suggested solutions involving subqueries, but the most overlooked aspect is the highly specific set of ordering clauses that causes the correct index to be used - in the right traversal direction, no less.

**Additional Advantages**

- Easily adjustable for min (`ASC`) vs. max (`DESC`).
- Winner per group can be composite, e.g. `timestamp, id`. (This also allows us to disambiguate non-unique winners, such as "latest timestamp".)
- Group key can be composite, e.g. `company_id, department_name`.
- Easily extended with a `WHERE` on which groups to select.
- Easily extended with a `WHERE` on what items to ignore, both indexed (`id >= 1000`) and non-indexed (`is_deleted = 0`).

**Why does this work [optimally]?**

Imagine leafing through the physical phone book, finding the last entry for each town, i.e. the entry with that town's alphabetically greatest name. How would you do it?

You would start at the very end. The very last entry in the book is the group maximum of the last town. It is the first result row that you encounter.

For each subsequent desired result row, you would binary search backwards, to the next-greatest town. At the point where the current town transitions into its predecessor, there is the predecessor's last row (alphabetically greatest name), i.e. your next result row. Repeat until no more towns.

Loosely speaking, the phone book is like a secondary index on `{ Town, Name, PhoneNumber }`, with `PhoneNumber` serving as the primary key. (I'm simplifying things for agument's sake, pretending phone numbers are assigned to one person and names form a single column.)

You are effectively doing a reverse seek through the index. By repeatedly jumping to the next town efficiently (thanks to binary search or a B-tree structure), the work is constrained by the number of *result* rows rather than the total number of rows. This is asymptotically optimal. And thanks to the reverse traversal direction, each town you encounter "starts" with its greatest row, your target. That is important: imagine the absurd amount of needless work if you'd have to scan all rows for a town.

Changing the solution to a groupwise-min is as trivial as changing the traversal direction, i.e. from `DESC` to `ASC`.

**RDBMS Notes**

- Whereas MySQL 8 correctly shows `Using index` for this, MySQL 5.7 shows a worrisome `Using where; Using index`, but it actually performs correctly. (Tested on a huge data set involving very large groups. Tens of thousands of results spread through hundreds of millions of records were obtained in ~3 seconds.)
- For SQL Server, the syntax is `SELECT TOP 1` instead of `SELECT ... LIMIT 1`.

Answer (score 2):

How about this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (name) *
FROM messages
ORDER BY name, id DESC;
```

I had similar issue (on postgresql tough) and on a 1M records table. This solution takes 1.7s vs 44s produced by the one with LEFT JOIN.
In my case I had to filter the corrispondant of your *name* field against NULL values, resulting in even better performances by 0.2 secs

Answer (score 2):

As of MySQL 8.0.14, this can also be achieved using [Lateral Derived Tables](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/lateral-derived-tables.html):

```
SELECT t.*
FROM messages t
JOIN LATERAL (
  SELECT name, MAX(id) AS id 
  FROM messages t1
  WHERE t.name = t1.name
  GROUP BY name
) trn ON t.name = trn.name AND t.id = trn.id
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=3d743790ddac81e6b5b99a762fa41c31)

Answer (score 2):

Yet another option without subqueries.

This solution uses MySQL [`LAST_VALUE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html#function_last-value) window function, exploiting [`Window Function Frame`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-functions-frames.html) available MySQL tool from .

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    LAST_VALUE(Id)            
        OVER(PARTITION BY Name 
             ORDER     BY Id 
             ROWS BETWEEN 0 PRECEDING 
                      AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING),
    Name,
    LAST_VALUE(Other_Columns)            
        OVER(PARTITION BY Name 
             ORDER     BY Id 
             ROWS BETWEEN 0 PRECEDING 
                      AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING)
FROM   
    tab
```

Try it [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/amnLC8Aw2JZz2FeGYEyCQc/0).

Comment: I am using T-SQL, this worked great for me, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Another approach :

Find the propertie with the max m2_price withing each program (n properties in 1 program) :

```
select * from properties p
join (
    select max(m2_price) as max_price 
    from properties 
    group by program_id
) p2 on (p.program_id = p2.program_id)
having p.m2_price = max_price
```

Answer (score 1):

Hope below Oracle query can help:

```
WITH Temp_table AS
(
    Select id, name, othercolumns, ROW_NUMBER() over (PARTITION BY name ORDER BY ID 
    desc)as rank from messages
)
Select id, name,othercolumns from Temp_table where rank=1
```

Answer (score 1):

What about:

```
select *, max(id) from messages group by name
```

I have tested it on sqlite and it returns all columns and max id value for all names.

Comment: First, your answer doesn't provides correct result in general for MySQL as the max ID and the rest of the columns could be from different records of the same group. Second, the same answer is already there (https://stackoverflow.com/a/9956875/1089242) like 9 years ago. Third, the question mentioned MySQL specifically. If your concern is about generic sql databases (or just sqlite), please check other questions, e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/3800551/1089242

Comment: I've tested it with sqlite only and it produced correct result. I haven't tried MySQL. The solution was simple, so I've posted it here. Sometimes simple is wrong. Can you share a non-working sqlite example?

Comment: @JacekBłocki This question is about MySQL.  Your answer may work in sqlite (I don't know, I don't have it), but it doesn't work in MySQL.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a more efficient version in 1 line, works as long as the table has a time stamp column.

```
SELECT Id, Name, SUBSTRING_INDEX(MAX(CONCAT(TimeStamp, ',', Other_Columns)), ',', -1)
FROM Messages
ORDER BY id DESC GROUP BY Name
```

This will return the latest record for the group on "Other_Columns"

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue

Subquery and join to the rescue

```
SELECT p."Date"
        ,p."Symbol"
        ,p."ratio_roll_qtr_ret"
    FROM PUBLIC."prices_vw" AS p
    JOIN (
        SELECT "Symbol"
            ,max("Date")
        FROM PUBLIC."prices_vw"
        GROUP BY "Symbol"
        ) AS sq ON p."Date" = sq."max"
        AND p."Symbol" = sq."Symbol"
    WHERE p."ratio_roll_qtr_ret" IS NOT NULL
    ORDER BY "ratio_roll_qtr_ret" DESC;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can group by counting and also get the last item of group like:

```
SELECT 
    user,
    COUNT(user) AS count,
    MAX(id) as last
FROM request 
GROUP BY user
```